# Twitter customising bootstrap and bootstrap-response stylessheets

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap

What is the best practice for customising the twitter bootstrap and response stylesheets so that they can still be upgraded in the future?

Overide the responsive @media rules in a custom stylesheet?

Comment: Do you mean like the options that are customized through their Customize page (font, colours, line-height, etc), or something more than that?

Comment: More than that, I'm doing a lot of custom styles for the different size @media options in the responsive stylesheet, do I just load my own bootstrap-responsive-custom.css to overwrite after loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using LESS, I would suggest you use LESS. Moreover, just import the base bootstrap.less into your style sheet at the beginning (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/dotless/bxNqBLtYmGM) and extend it from there. Try to use bootstraps variables for things like height, color, etc, too keep everything consistent.

From here when you update bootstrap, the new bootstrap.less should be included in your sheet next time the LESS file is built.

Note that I havn't personally tried this, but it should work no problem.